# CSV file generates new name - call powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to call a CSV file from a Powershell script, which I know how to do. However the problem is, I need to do this with a new CSV file name everyday ( a new CSV is generated everyday). Is there anyway to do this without having to change the name of the file on the PS script everyday?

```
$csv = Import-Csv '$D\path to csv'

$headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name

  foreach ($header in $headers) {
  foreach ($data in $csv.$header) {

   }

 }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get-Childitem` to get files/directories in a directory. You can combine it with `-Filter` to get only  CSVs, `Sort-Object` to sort by `LastWriteTime` (most recent CSV at the top) and `Select-Object` so you only get the most recent file.

```
$myCsv = Get-ChildItem '$D\path to csv' -Filter *.csv |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1

$csv = Import-Csv $myCsv

$headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name

  foreach ($header in $headers) {
  foreach ($data in $csv.$header) {

   }

 }
```